# Can't reach my (final) button inside my OnClickListener function

Tags: java, android

My final goal of this snippet is to:

1. call a Dialog(Interface) from a button.
2. let the end user select an option (in a list of 5 options)
3. change the button text to the selected option

Currently I have this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   setLayoutState();
   // rest of code omitted
}
```

then the setLayoutState() that instatiates the button

```
public void setLayoutState() {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button rate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ratebutton);
    rate.setOnClickListener(onRatePress); 
}
```

**So here:** *setOnClickListener calls to a separate function (to keep things clean, the Activity has got a lot of buttons)*

```
private final View.OnClickListener onRatePress = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                context, R.array.rates, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Rate this item!")
       .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Common.makeToast(context,adapter.getItem(which) + "", 3000);
                Button rate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ratebutton);
                rate.setText(adapter.getItem(which)+"");
                // TODO: user specific action
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
};
```

While **this works fine** I was wondering if there is a way I can pull this off **without** redeclaring the Button rate inside the Dialog's onClick

I've already tried declaring the button as final in the top part, but that won't let me call the button in the Dialog's onClick.

Comment: maybe declaring the Button globally without final will help.

Comment: Show how you declared your button, it should be a valid reference here.

Comment: @Snicolas  edited my code for  you to show you how (in what context) I declared my bttn. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

A variable in Java has a scope. It is always available inside the block (a pair of braces {} ) that contains its declaration, and in any block contained by this block. But not ouside.

Thus if you declare your button inside a method, it is not accessible outside of this method.
You button is only accessible inside drupappSetUploadLayout.

if you want it to be accessible to all methods, then put it inside the class body directly. Such a variable is called a field and fields are accessible to all methods.

```
public class A {
  private Button b;

  public void foo() {
    b=null;
  }
}
```

b can be accessed by all methods.

Read more about the basics of java, you should consider making small J2SDK programs before starting with android.

Comment: idd good answer. wish I could vote thisone +1 but don't have enough rep :/

Answer (score 0):

The View v that is a parameter refers to the button that was clicked... so you could remove the redeclaration of the button and use

```
 ( (Button) v).setText(adapter.getItem(which)+"");
```

Comment: This is true with View.OnclickListener, not for DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Comment: @Snicolas : true story ... as stated I'm inside the DialogInterface's OnClickListener when I'm trying to reach the button for re-assignment ...