# basic use about EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a EditText , a textView and a button,

I need to set my textView with the value of my EditText when a button is touched,
but I have a variable not being recognized [sorry noob on android here]

```
public class XynthaCalcTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //buttons
        benefixPaButtonPressed(); 
        benefixAdultButtonPressed();
        xynthaButtonPressed(); 
        calculateButtonPressed();

        //textField == EditText
        final EditText et;
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    public void calculateButtonPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.result);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Log.d("myTag",  "result biatch");

                String text=et.getText().toString();

                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                 msg.show();

            }

        });

    }
}
```

so on the line with `String text=et.getText().toString();`
I have the error `et cannot be resolved`

So ...
how to declare my et Edit text so the button Class can see it?

thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't reach my (final) button inside my OnClickListener function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432851/cant-reach-my-final-button-inside-my-onclicklistener-function)

Comment: Check at the link of duplicate, you need to take more care of variable scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make et a field instead, having the final modifier makes no sense to me there.

```
public class XynthaCalcTestActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText et;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //buttons
        benefixPaButtonPressed(); 
        benefixAdultButtonPressed();
        xynthaButtonPressed(); 
        calculateButtonPressed();

        //textField == EditText
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    public void calculateButtonPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.result);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Log.d("myTag",  "result biatch");

                String text=et.getText().toString();

                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                 msg.show();

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

define Edittext field "et" as class variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it can be help you...

```
public class XynthaCalcTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //buttons
   // benefixPaButtonPressed(); 
   // benefixAdultButtonPressed();
   // xynthaButtonPressed(); 
   // calculateButtonPressed();

    //textField == EditText

    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            textView.setText(text);
            Toast.makeText(XynthaCalcTestActivity.this,text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: Replace with your original id, which you taken in main.xml